# useState is not a function inside useEffect

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I'm new to react native. I'm trying to use state and effect hooks.

```
const {isKeyboardOpen, setIsKeyboardOpen} = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', () => setIsKeyboardOpen(true))
    const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', () => setIsKeyboardOpen(false))

    return () => {
        keyboardDidShowListener.remove()
        keyboardDidHideListener.remove()
    }
}, [])
```

But it throws an error

> setIsKeyboardOpen is not a function.

Am I not allow to use state hook inside effect hook?[image]

Comment: Try to rebuild your app, sometimes rebuild helps.

Comment: You have curly braces on your state (`{ }`), `useState` is declared with square brackets. Change it to `[isKeyboardOpen, setIsKeyboardOpen] = ...`

Comment: I've been struggling for almost a day now, just to find out it was square brackets. Hahaha. Thank you @Konstantin

Answer (score 1):

Hi I used it in my code but not getting any error. Please check your code-

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import {Platform, Switch, Keyboard} from 'react-native';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const SwitchComponent = (props) => {
 const [isEnabled, setIsEnabled] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      () => setIsEnabled(true),
    );
    const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidHide',
      () => setIsEnabled(false),
    );

return () => {
  keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
  keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
 };
}, []);

return (
<Switch/>
 );
};

export default SwitchComponent;![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bByT.jpg)
```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the response. It's strange. All the tutorials I've seen, state is working inside effect hook. I have just copy and pasted my code here to make sure we have same code.